# Using grep/sed to parse BASH cmdline arguments

Tags: bash, grep

I got a script that expects two args (filename and MD5hashval).  I can extract just the hex output of MD5sum using md5sum test.sh | grep -om1 '^[0-9a-f]*.' For some reason, the same cmd fails when invoked from a script.  Whats the best way to check cmdline arguments passed to a Bash script?  Here's what the code looks like:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":f:s" opt; do
  case $opt in
    f)

      FILENAME=`echo $OPTARG | sed 's/[-a-zA-Z0-9]*=//'`
      echo ${FILENAME}
      ;;
    s)

       MD5SUM=`echo $OPTARG | grep -om1 '^[0-9a-f]*'` 
       echo $MD5SUM
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

Comment: It appears that `-f` and `-s` get identical arguments, and you are trying to extract the appropriate pieces for each. I would argue it should be the user's responsibility to supply the correct argument for each option, rather than expecting the script to do it for them.

Answer (score 2):

Since the `s` option requires an argument, you need to place a colon after it. It should be:

```
while getopts "f:s:" opt; do
...
```

From the `getopts` man page:

> if a character  is  followed  by  a colon,  the  option  is  expected
>   to have an argument, which should be separated from it by white space.

Answer (score 0):

My first action would be to place a debug line before your actual command:

```
echo "[$OPTARG]"
MD5SUM=`echo $OPTARG | grep -om1 '^[0-9a-f]*'`
```

But it actually has to do with the fact that `s` is not followed by a colon in your `getopts` options string. You should use `f:s:` instead:

> ... optstring contains the option characters to be recognized; if  a character is **followed** by a colon, the option is expected to have an argument, which should be separated from it by white space.

And, just as an aside, I think your error lines should be `-$opt` rather than `-$OPTARG`.

Comment: I tried adding the colon after the s switch. Now -f switch accepts punctuation characters for some reason and the -s switch is blank even when I pass a valid argument.  Any ideas on how to debug the parameters/args passed to the script?  It works fine when I don't use grep or set at all like chepner suggested. Where can I find an example on how to parse cmdline args? Here's what it looks like now 
while getopts ":f:s" opt; do...

Comment: why should I use -$opt rather than -$OPTARG, the built-in variable? @paxdiablo

Comment: @Logical, Because `opt` is the option (`f` in `-f xyzzy`) and `OPTARG` is the option argument (`xyzzy`).

Comment: that works but how come I can't grep the $OPTARG using a pipe?

Comment: You can, you should first figure out what optarg _is._

Comment: OPTARG is the actually argument attached to the parameter.  I think my Emacs editor is either outdated or slow.  For some reason, `echo $OPTARG | grep -om1 '^[0-9a-f]*'` didn't work when I first tried.  Now I'm starting to see how the functions works. Any ideas on what >&2 represents? I think its for error handling...so it gets transferred to the proper stdout stream....I could be wrong.....